# PHP - Como comparar uma data que vem do banco de dados MySql com o dia atual?

Tags: php, mysql, data

Eu tenho uma coluna no banco de dados que está no formato `DATE (Y-m-d)`.
No código php eu recupero essa string e tenho que comparar com a data atual e essa é a condição que estou usando:

```
$dtEntrega=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($row["dtEnterga"])); 
$today = strtotime(date("Y-m-d")); 

if($today>=$dtEntrega){
//Fazer algo
}
```

Mas esse código sempre retorna verdadeiro, mesmo se a data de entrega esta armazenada no banco de dados com data no futuro.
Alguém sabe onde estou errando ou está faltando algo?

---

Edição:
A pergunta não é igual à citada pelo moderador pois o resuldato daquela não se aplica ao meu contexto.

Comment: Parece estar tudo ok: 2016-05-30 e 2016-07-02. Por isso não estou entendendo.

Comment: Da uma procurada pela classe DateTime

Comment: Oi João, não é a mesma questão. Eu já tinha passado por ela antes de perguntar. Observe a reposta que tem 16 pontos. É exatamente o que eu fiz e não está dando certo. `if(strtotime($data1) > strtotime($data2))`. A resposta que deu certo foi a do Nelson. Um tem que passar para string e o outro não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade é só retirar o strtotime da variavel $today:

```
<?php

   $dtEntrega=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($row["dtEnterga"])); 
   $today = date("Y-m-d"); 
   if($today>=$dtEntrega){
      echo ' alguma coisa';
   }
```

Quado isso ocorre um var_dump na variável já elucidaria o problema.

Saída antes da correção :

```
  $dtEntrega ===> string(10) "2016-05-30"
  $today    ===> int(1464652800)
```

Após correção:

```
  $dtEntrega ===> string(10) "2016-05-30"
  $today    ===> string(10) "2016-05-30"
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de fazer isso, é usando o objeto [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php), e verificar o número em formato "timestamp", apenas resetando os milisegundos:

```
$dataAtual = new DateTime();

function formatDateObj($dateString) {
    $dateString = new DateTime($dateString);
    $dateString->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.uO'); 
    return $dateString;
}

$dataEntrega = formatDateObj($row["dtEnterga"].' 00:00:00');

if ($dataAtual->getTimestamp() >= $dateEntrega->getTimestamp()) {
   //Fazer algo
}
```